# PHP: socket_connect is working, but not socket_bind

Tags: php, sockets

I am trying to connect via TCP Socket to a third party product.  I am able to do so (and send a message successfully) with the following code:

```
  if (isset($port) and ($socket=socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) and (socket_connect($socket, $address , $port)))
  {
    $text="Connection successful on IP $address, port $port";
    $data = "<msg id=1>text</msg>" . $newline; 
    socket_send($socket, $data, strlen($data), MSG_DONTROUTE);
    $text .= socket_strerror(socket_last_error());
    socket_close($socket);
  }
```

The down side is that I also need to listen on this socket.  As I understand it, I first need to bind, rather than using connect.  When I run the code below, I get this error when calling socket_bind

> Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.

code (snippet from a TCP Class, I have verified that the IP address, port, etc are the same in both snippets):

```
            $this->Socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    $result = socket_bind($this->Socket, $this->Host, $this->Port);
    $result = socket_listen($this->Socket, 3) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");
    $spawn = socket_accept($this->Socket) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");
```

How is it that I can connect using socket_connect but not socket_bind?  Is it correct that I need to use socket_bind if I want to listen on this socket?

I am running PHP on a Windows XP Apache installation (Zend).  I should also mention that the only other application running when I try to execute this code is the third party program to which I am trying to connect.

Thank you for any insight.

Comment: When you say "I need to listen on this socket", do you mean you need to send data to **and** receive data from the server you've connected to? If so, you don't need to use bind/listen/accept at all. Just use send/receive to send and receive data once the connection has been established. If you want to connect to a remote host **and** listen for connections from a remote host, then you need two separate sockets to do that.

Comment: Ahhh! So listen refers to listening for connections rather than listening for communication?  I'm sure I read that somewhere else, but it didn't sink in.  What I need to do is make a connection, then send and receive messages on that connection.  So if listening doesn't refer to triggering some kind of response when a communication is sent to my program from the other side of the connection, how would I do that?  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: You could use stream_socket_server for that?

Comment: Thanks Shiplu, I'll take a closer look at that as well.